# Java: How to write a generalized function for this?

Tags: java

How to a write a single generalized for these? I mean the function should take parameters and return the desired string.

```
String fullName = driver.findElement(By.className("full-name")).getText();
String title = driver.findElement(By.className("title")).getText();
String locality = driver.findElement(By.className("locality")).getText();
String industry = driver.findElement(By.className("industry")).getText();
String connections = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='member-connections']/strong")).getText();
String profileLink = driver.findElement(By.className("view-public-profile")).getText();
```

The function should be something like this:

```
String getInfo(String className, String byType) {
     return driver.findElement(By.byType(className)).getText();
}
```

EDIT:

I have written this function, but I am not sure how to append byType with By.

```
static String getInfo(WebDriver driver, String byType, String byParam) {
        return driver.findElement(By. + byType + (byParam)).getText();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you maybe write some sudo-code for what you're looking for? I'm not clear on the question.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Do you have some kind of object that you would use to store this information in?  If you don't (or for some reason you don't believe you need one), then what you have is likely fine.

Comment: Later I'd be saving the info in json object/file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems way easier than others are answering so I'm going to put my neck on the line. and say, what's wrong with this...

```
public String get(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    return driver.findElement(by).getText();
}
```

..and using it like...

```
String a = get(urDriver, By.className(someName));
String b = get(urDriver, By.xpath(somePath));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
public String byXpath(String xpath) {
  return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).getText();
}

public String byClass(String $class) {
  return driver.findElement(By.className($class)).getText();
}
```

**Edited:**

```
public String by(By by) {
    return driver.findElement(by).getText();
}

String x = by(By.className(name));
String y = by(By.xpath(path));
```

Comment: I just want a single function because apart from byXpath, byClass; there are other types as well, like byCss, etc. I don't want to write separate functions for those.

Comment: Then you can write another function that looks at the string expression it got and dispatches to the appropriate one.